# ImageView in a Custom Dialog - fill_parent does not work and my dialog is small

Tags: android, dialog, imageview, fill-parent

I have a simple request: I have to put some pictures (some small resolution, some big resolution) in a dialog and display them fullscreen.

I tried this:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
int picId = Integer.valueOf(webcamCursor.getString(webcamCursor
        .getColumnIndex("_id")));
dialog.setTitle(webcamCursor.getString(webcamCursor
        .getColumnIndex("City")));
image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);            
new DownloadPicTask().execute(Snippets.getUrlFromCat(picId, cat));
dialog.show();
```

And my layout is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/layout_root"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:padding="10dip"
               />
</LinearLayout>
```

As I wrote fill_parent everywhere, shouldn't the dialog take the full screen?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try that:

```
dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().width = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this will work

//Grab the window of the dialog, and change the width
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
        //This makes the dialog take up the full width
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        window.setAttributes(lp);
```